# Learn Python The Hard Way Ex40

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm learning python from the book called "Learn python the hard way" and i came across this block of code in exercise40

```
cities = {'CA': 'San Francisco', 'MI': 'Detroit', 'FL': 'Jacksonville'}

cities['NY'] = 'New York'
cities['OR'] = 'Portland'

def find_city(themap, state):
    if state in themap:
        return themap[state]
    else:
        return "Not found."

# ok pay attention!
cities['_find'] = find_city

while True:
    print "State? (ENTER to quit)",
    state = raw_input("> ")
    if not state: break

# this line is the most important ever! study!
city_found = cities['_find'](cities, state)
print city_found
```

1.Is it necessary to add "find_city" function to the dictionary?

2.Can i remove "themap" argument in the function "find_city"?

Here is my new code and it can still run without any error:

```
cities = {"CA" : "San Francisco", "MI" : "Detroit", "FL" : "Jacksonville"}

cities["NY"]= "New York"
cities["OR"] = "Portland"

def find_city(state):
    if state in cities:
        return cities[state]
    else:
        return "Not Found."

while True:
    print "State? (ENTER to quit)",
    state = raw_input(">")
    if not state:
        break
    city_found = find_city(state)
    print city_found
```

Comment: I think the method is put inside the dictionary to demonstrate that you _can_ call it by referencing through the dictionary as well.

Answer (score 5):

1. no, it is not.
2. yes you can.

And as a side note, many of the top [python](/questions/tagged/python) answerers here on Stack Overflow do not recommend using Learn Python the Hard Way - quite contrary. As a newcomer, in 2017, your time would be more well-spent learning Python 3 and using some other resource.

Comment: Not much of 2017 left though :)

Comment: Well, even worse :D

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's strange, to put a function in a dictionary with cities. I wouldn't do that, but I don't know, what the author want to demonstrate with.

It is not a good idea, to rely on the global variable `cities` in `find_city`.

Usually, you would use `.get`:

```
def find_city(mapping, state):
    return mapping.get(state, "Not Found.")

while True:
    print "State? (ENTER to quit)",
    state = raw_input(">")
    if not state:
        break
    city_found = find_city(cities, state)
    print city_found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but the first 'codepiece' example stores a "functionpointer" for the find-function inside the dictionary itself so you can use the function by using a key of `'_find'` and supply the parameters to the found value (the FP) for this key.

I do not know the book, but probably this is done on a purpose, like f.e. to teach you that "values" in a dictionary can be of different types - maybe even an introduction to study functions as objects and how to use them....

In a real world example I would not do this, I might wrap the whole dictionary in a class and supply class methods *IF* (and thats a big if) there are other concerns that leads me to wrap stuff for this class...

All in all it is a very contreived example (in germany we would say "An den Haaren herbeigezogen" wich roughly translates to "pulled by it's hairs" (word by word) or "pulled out of the a..")

I think you are better of using the python3 website and its examples to learn - there are plenty of things to gain there - and study the documentation.

Start here:  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/